# Trying to append <li> as last in nested <ul>

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append a li as the last item within a dynamic nested list. I get the list from mysql and add new list items by clicking on the parent ul then using that id as a parent identifier append a new child li.

```
$("#"+id).last("li:last").after(html);
```

No matter what I try it is still appending it as the first item not as the last. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Try this one. The jQuery append() method inserts content AT THE END of the selected HTML elements. $("ul").append("<li>Something</li>"); http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @WesleyLachenal's way would work. This is another way which is more similar to your current code `$("#"+id+" li").last().after(html);` http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_last.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, Wesley your suggestion works fine but how would it I append it based on unique parent id?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in a few different ways.. here are two...

```js
var theHTML = '<li><strong style="color: red;">NEW</strong></li>';

// Add using insertAfter
$('#new').on('click', function() {
  $( theHTML ).insertAfter("#theList li:last");
});

//Add using append
$('#append').on('click', function() {
  $('#theList').append( theHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="new">Add Another After</button>
<button id="append">Append Another</button>
<ul id="theList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```